# Serial not displaying sketch for MPU6050

Tags: serial, mpu6050

I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9lZ5Qy5S2s

Where he provided the code below. The problem I'm having is the serial monitor shows nothing. I tried changing the baud to 115200 and still nothing showed up. I'm using an Arduino nano.

Update: I wrote a Serial.print in each function (printing the name of the function), and I found it just printed up to "recordAccelRegisters" then stopped. Then I put a Serial.print after each line in the function, and it prints until the line 
`while(Wire.available() < 6);`
Is this a problem with the while function or I2C?

Ok, so I reinstalled Arduino and got this message on the serial print with the I2C test:

"Scanning... I2C device found at address 0x69  ! done."

```
#include <Wire.h>

long accelX, accelY, accelZ;
float gForceX, gForceY, gForceZ;

long gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
float rotX, rotY, rotZ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  setupMPU();
}


void loop() {
  recordAccelRegisters();
  recordGyroRegisters();
  printData();
  delay(100);
}

void setupMPU(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //This is the I2C address of the MPU (b1101000/b1101001 for AC0 low/high datasheet sec. 9.2)
  Wire.write(0x6B); //Accessing the register 6B - Power Management (Sec. 4.28)
  Wire.write(0b00000000); //Setting SLEEP register to 0. (Required; see Note on p. 9)
  Wire.endTransmission();  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x1B); //Accessing the register 1B - Gyroscope Configuration (Sec. 4.4) 
  Wire.write(0x00000000); //Setting the gyro to full scale +/- 250deg./s 
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x1C); //Accessing the register 1C - Acccelerometer Configuration (Sec. 4.5) 
  Wire.write(0b00000000); //Setting the accel to +/- 2g
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
}

void recordAccelRegisters() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x3B); //Starting register for Accel Readings
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0b1101000,6); //Request Accel Registers (3B - 40)
  while(Wire.available() < 6);
  accelX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store first two bytes into accelX
  accelY = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store middle two bytes into accelY
  accelZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store last two bytes into accelZ
  processAccelData();
}

void processAccelData(){
  gForceX = accelX / 16384.0;
  gForceY = accelY / 16384.0; 
  gForceZ = accelZ / 16384.0;
}

void recordGyroRegisters() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x43); //Starting register for Gyro Readings
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0b1101000,6); //Request Gyro Registers (43 - 48)
  while(Wire.available() < 6);
  gyroX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store first two bytes into accelX
  gyroY = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store middle two bytes into accelY
  gyroZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); //Store last two bytes into accelZ
  processGyroData();
}

void processGyroData() {
  rotX = gyroX / 131.0;
  rotY = gyroY / 131.0; 
  rotZ = gyroZ / 131.0;
}

void printData() {
  Serial.print("Gyro (deg)");
  Serial.print(" X=");
  Serial.print(rotX);
  Serial.print(" Y=");
  Serial.print(rotY);
  Serial.print(" Z=");
  Serial.print(rotZ);
  Serial.print(" Accel (g)");
  Serial.print(" X=");
  Serial.print(gForceX);
  Serial.print(" Y=");
  Serial.print(gForceY);
  Serial.print(" Z=");
  Serial.println(gForceZ);
}
```

https://github.com/VRomanov89/EEEnthusiast/blob/master/MPU-6050%20Implementation/MPU6050_Implementation/MPU6050_Implementation.ino

Comment: I put a serial.print in the first line of each function. It stops after `recordAccelRegisters`

Comment: tried http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner same problem

Comment: Got it. I used the address from the I2C test and everything looks great. Guess I'll have to do this for any cheap modules I get on ebay :)

Answer (score 1):

Ground the AD0 pin. I thought the address should be set to 0x68 without this, but from what I've seen it fluctuates between 0x68 and 0x69. If you want the address to be 0x69 short the AD0 pin to 5V. I guess this would be useful if you need to use 2 MPU6050s with different I2C addresses without doing something in software. Haven't looked into that yet

Still, the I2C scanner for arduino may be useful for detecting the address/debugging: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner